# Python: Check if a numpy array contains an object with specific attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I want to check if there is any object with a specific attribute in my `numpy` array:

```
class Test:
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

l = numpy.empty( (2,2), dtype=object)
l[0][0] = Test("A")
l[0][1] = Test("B")
l[1][0] = Test("C")
l[1][1] = Test("D")
```

I know that following line of code working for a list, but what is the alternative process for a numpy array?

```
print numpy.any(l[:,0].name == "A")
```

Comment: possible duplicated. see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088625/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-a-numpy-array

Comment: I believe this is another situation since I have an array of objects. [The other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088625/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-a-numpy-array) asking how to find about the existence of a value in an array.

Comment: Object arrays are little more than glorified lists.  They can have a 2d shape, but they don't have the math powers of a regular array.  Why are you using them?

Comment: Actually, I need my data to be exactly in a 2D structure.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number SO questions about object dtype arrays, and even some about getting or testing the attributes of the elements of such arrays.  The general point is that such an array behaves much like a list.  For the most part you have to iterate over the array as though it were a list.  Most of the cool things that you can do with numeric arrays like `add`, `multiply` etc do not apply.  Or your objects have to implement specific methods for the actions to propagate down to the objects.

```
In [15]: class Test:
    ...:     def __init__(self,name):
    ...:         self.name=name
    ...:     def __repr__(self):   # added for nice display
    ...:         return 'Test:%s'%self.name
    ...:     
In [16]: A = np.empty((2,2),dtype=object)
```

I can assign all the values at once using `flat[:]` and list:

```
In [17]: A.flat[:]=[Test('A'),Test('B'),Test('C'),Test('D')]

In [18]: A      # try this display without the `repr`
Out[18]: 
array([[Test:A, Test:B],
       [Test:C, Test:D]], dtype=object)
```

this returns False because I did not define a `cmp` for the class; that is `Test('A')==Test('A')` is also False.

```
In [19]: Test('A') in A
Out[19]: False


In [20]: A[0,1].name
Out[20]: 'B'
```

This is true because it is an identity test

```
In [21]: A[0,1] in A
Out[21]: True
```

Since `A` is 2d, a simple list comprehension on it does not work, at least not for testing attributes.  `a` in this case is a row of `A`, a 1d object array:

```
In [23]: [a.name for a in A]
...
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'name'
```

To get the names I have to iterated on `A.flat`; I can apply the `in` test to the resulting list:

```
In [24]: [a.name for a in A.flat]
Out[24]: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
In [25]: 'B' in [a.name for a in A.flat]
Out[25]: True
```

`np.vectorize` is a way of writing functions that operate on arrays of various shapes.  It uses `np.frompyfunc`, which in this case works just as well, if not better.

```
In [27]: foo = np.frompyfunc(lambda a: a.name, 1,1)
In [28]: foo(A)
Out[28]: 
array([['A', 'B'],
       ['C', 'D']], dtype=object)
In [29]: 'C' in foo(A)
Out[29]: True
```

Or I could define a version that does the `name` equality test.  Notice this takes 2 inputs

```
In [30]: bar = np.frompyfunc(lambda a,b: b == a.name, 2, 1)

In [32]: bar(A,'C')
Out[32]: 
array([[False, False],
       [True, False]], dtype=object)
```

I can even test 2 arrays against each other with broadcasting:

```
In [37]: bar(A,np.array(['A','D'])[:,None,None])
Out[37]: 
array([[[True, False],
        [False, False]],

       [[False, False],
        [False, True]]], dtype=object)
```

`frompyfunc` iterates as the `[a for a in A.flat]` does, but is somewhat faster, and throws all the power of numpy broadcasting at the task.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way would be creating your array object by inheriting from Numpy's ndarray object. Then use a custom function for checking the existence of your object based on the name attribute:

```
In [71]: class Myarray(np.ndarray):
   ....:         def __new__(cls, inputarr):
   ....:                 obj = np.asarray(inputarr).view(cls)
   ....:                 return obj
   ....:         def custom_contain(self, name):
   ....:                 return any(obj.name == name for obj in self.flat)
```

Demo:

```
In [4]: A = np.empty((2,2),dtype=object)    
In [8]: A.flat[:] = [Test("A"), Test("B"), Test("C"), Test("D")]

In [9]: A
Out[9]: 
array([[<__main__.Test instance at 0x7fae0a14ddd0>,
        <__main__.Test instance at 0x7fae0a14de18>],
       [<__main__.Test instance at 0x7fae0a14de60>,
        <__main__.Test instance at 0x7fae0a14dea8>]], dtype=object)

In [11]: A = Myarray(A)

In [12]: A.custom_contain('C')
Out[12]: True

In [13]: A.custom_contain('K')
Out[13]: False
```

Comment: Thank you for your informative comment, but still you are having a list as your  array, which is totally working with any().

Comment: How about changeing the code to this:

    l = np.empty( (2,2), dtype=object)
l = Myarray(l)
print l

l[0][0] = Test("A")
l[0][1] = Test("B")
l[1][0] = Test("C")
l[1][1] = Test("D")

print l.custom_contain('C')

Comment: The answer iterates over the array, just as though it were a list.  That is typical object array operations

Comment: @hpaulj So you mean, the custom_contain function  is still working if you pass an array to the Myarray constructor? which is not, unfortunately.

Comment: I mean `custom_contain` has a `for obj in self` phrase.  If `self` is a 2d array it may need `for obj in self.flat`.

Comment: @SetarehBehroozi Yes, I missed that, but as hpaulj described you can use `self.flat` within generator expression in order to loop over the flatten array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm clearly not proficient in numpy but couldn't you just do something like:

```
numpy.any([ x.name=='A' for x in l[:,0] ])
```

edit:
(Google tells me that) it's possible to iterate over arrays with `nditer`; is this what you want?

```
numpy.any([ x.name=='A' for x in numpy.nditer(l) ])
```

Comment: I edited my answer; I'm still unsure about what you want to do, though.