# Check if single element is contained in Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I just want to check if a numpy array contains a single number quickly similar to contains for a list.  Is there a concise way to do this?

```
a = np.array(9,2,7,0)
a.contains(0)  == true
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088625/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-a-numpy-array

Comment: `np.array(9,2,7,0)` raises an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to check if a value exists in a NumPy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088625/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `0 in a`. i.e

```
a = np.array([9,2,7,0])
0 in a
```

Answer (score 6):

if a is a numpy array:

```
a = np.array([1, 2])
```

then use:

```
1 in a
```

which returns true, while:

```
0 in a
```

returns false

Answer (score 5):

I timed some methods to do this in python 3.7:

```py
import numpy as np
rnd = np.random.RandomState(42)
one_d = rnd.randint(100, size=10000)
n_d = rnd.randint(100, size=(10000, 10000))
searched = 42

# One dimension
%timeit if np.isin(one_d, searched, assume_unique=True).any(): pass
%timeit if np.in1d(one_d, searched, assume_unique=True).any(): pass
%timeit if searched in one_d: pass
%timeit if one_d[np.searchsorted(one_d, searched)] == searched: pass
%timeit if np.count_nonzero(one_d == searched): pass

print("------------------------------------------------------------------")

# N dimensions
%timeit if np.isin(n_d, searched, assume_unique=True).any(): pass
%timeit if np.in1d(n_d, searched, assume_unique=True).any(): pass
%timeit if searched in n_d: pass
%timeit if np.count_nonzero(n_d == searched): pass
```

```
>>> 42.8 µs ± 79.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
>>> 38.6 µs ± 76.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
>>> 16.4 µs ± 57.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
>>> 4.7 µs ± 62.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
>>> 12.1 µs ± 69.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
>>> ------------------------------------------------------------------
>>> 239 ms ± 1.04 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
>>> 241 ms ± 1.17 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
>>> 156 ms ± 2.78 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
>>> 163 ms ± 527 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

The fastest for 1d arrays is the one proposed above of `np.searchsorted` however it cannot be used for ndarrays. Also `np.count_nonzero` is the fastest but it is not much faster than the pythonic `in`, so I would recommend to use `in`.

Comment: Sometimes, in 1D, converting `one_d` to `set_one_d = set(one_d.tolist())` and then checking `searched in set_one_d` is so much faster, if that initial overhead is acceptable in your use case. And for small 1D arrays, the overhead of converting to a set is so low that it is even faster than `np.searchsorted()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
x = 0
if x in a:
   print 'find'
```