# Python - Check Zero Floating Point Value in Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, floating-point, zero

How to check for a given NumPy array of any dimension (1D, 2D, or 3D) if it contains any zero floating point value (0.0). For example, this 2D array:

```
[[0.07181809 0.76638862 0.0]
 [0.93566192 0.13161751 0.85768675]]
```

Is there any function that check for above condition and return `True`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `np.isclose(arr, 0).any()`

Comment: you can also do `not np.all(arr)`

Comment: It turns out that checking with `0 in arr` is fastest of 3 method listed here. not np.all(arr)` and `np.isclose(arr, 0).any()` takes more time than simple `in`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
my_numpy_array = numpy.array(
  [[0.07181809, 0.76638862, 0.0],
   [0.93566192, 0.13161751, 0.85768675]]
)
0.0 in my_numpy_array
```

See also: [Check if single element is contained in Numpy Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45062340/check-if-single-element-is-contained-in-numpy-array/45062498).