# How do I create a numpy array that corresponds to whether a point is inside a numpy array of polygons?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Here is my attempt, but I get the error 
`"AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'contains'"` .

If any of you can help me to understand how to define `'y'` in this code such that it is a numpy array with 1s corresponding to the index of polygons that contain the specified point and 0s corresponding to the index of polygons that do not contain the specified point I  would appreciate it.

```
polygonss=[]
for i in range(0, len(verts)):
    polygonc = Polygon(verts[i])
    print (polygonc)
    polygonss.append(polygonc)
print (polygonss)
p=np.array(polygonss)
print (p)
vertsf=meshinformation_fine.celltoverticesandcentroid(0)[0]
point = Point(vertsf[0])
y=np.where(p.contains(point), 0, 1)
print (y)
```

Comment: `Point` and `Polygon` are not part of `numpy`.  They come from somewhere else (`matplotlib.patches`?  `shapely`? Find out where.)  That's why you can't expect a `numpy` array of such objects to inherit the behavior of the objects themselves.

Answer (score 1):

A numpy object array is not particularly useful to you here, you may as well do the process with a list comprehension

```
y = [p.contains(point) for p in polygonss]
```

However, if you are doing this for a large number of points, then I encourage you to read up on [geopandas](http://geopandas.org/) which enables you to do vectorised computations on geometries and apply them to tabular data.

Answer (score 0):

First the error message is actually what keeps you from succeeding. `.ndarray object` just do not have that attribute `contains`

Which renders your question to one of those [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088625/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-a-numpy-array), discussing on how to check whether an element is within a numpy Array.

One Thing that could work instead of contains is something following that line, if I understood correctly:

```
y = np.zeros(len(p))
for counter in range (0, len(p)):
    if point in p[counter]:
        y[counter] = 1
```

**Note:** It would help if you would add exemplary values for your variables and the then expected output.